# How to Mass Change with Regex

Tags: regex

Before

```
Live! => [ cambax83@gmail.com:xxxxx ] + [Name: Cameron - Following: 225 - Follower: 2 - Bio: GAFY - Location: Australia - URL: Empty - Translator: No - Verified: No (Joined At Wed Oct 12 21:54:04 +0000 2011 [1256 Days])]
Live! => [ kingrozny@hotmail.com:xxxxx ] + [Name: Edgar - Following: 236 - Follower: 9 - Bio: Empty - Location: Empty - URL: Empty - Translator: No - Verified: No (Joined At Sun Jan 15 07:45:52 +0000 2012 [1162 Days])]
Live! => [ voonshin@gmail.com:xxxxx ] + [Name: Voonshin - Following: 381 - Follower: 1 - Bio: Empty - Location: Empty - URL: Empty - Translator: No - Verified: No (Joined At Thu Sep 20 04:14:04 +0000 2012 [913 Days])]
Live! => [ y0ng4n@gmail.com:xxxxx ] + [Name: Surabaya Jaya - Following: 539 - Follower: 0 - Bio: Surabaya Jaya merupakan Distributor Peralatan Safety, Sarung tangan, Terpal, dsb. Distributor kita berpusat di kota Surabaya dan memiliki cabang di Balikpapan. - Location: Balikpapan - URL: Empty - Translator: No - Verified: No (Joined At Fri Aug 01 11:38:33 +0000 2014 [233 Days])]
Live! => [ Honeybee104@hotmail.com:xxxxx ] + [Name: Diane - Following: 84 - Follower: 1 - Bio: Empty - Location: Empty - URL: Empty - Translator: No - Verified: No (Joined At Fri Jul 25 23:03:26 +0000 2014 [239 Days])]
```

After :

```
cambax83@gmail.com:xxxxx
kingrozny@hotmail.com:com:xxxxx
voonshin@gmail.com:com:xxxxx
y0ng4n@gmail.com:com:xxxxx
Honeybee104@hotmail.com:com:xxxxx
```

How to mass Clean with Regex, please with demo on https://regex101.com/ ! :)

Comment: _“please with demo”_ – _questions_ please with at least some efforts of your own.

Comment: see before and after ,, I want to change the mass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see demo here https://regex101.com/r/cN7vT8/1

```
/(\w+@\w+\.\w{2,4}:xxxxx)/gm
```

and for replace demo here https://regex101.com/r/cN7vT8/2

```
var re = /.*\[ (\w+@\w+\.\w{2,4}:xxxxx).*/gm; 
var subst = '$1';  
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score 0):

According the poor spec, i'll do https://regex101.com/r/mI4mJ6/1

```
\[\s*(.*xxxx) \]
```

Comment: You're right, i was trying to use the "specific" xxxx part :)

Answer (score 0):

**Find**  :   `^[^\[]*\[\s*|\s*\].*$`

**Replace**:`Empty string`.

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/32

http://regexr.com/3alde

Comment: In regexr, it only highlights the first and last bits, not like your regex101 solution.

Comment: @ha9u63ar you have to use `replace` and correct flags `gm`. http://regexr.com/3alde